# Image won't load?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, parse-platform, uistoryboardsegue

Image that i pass from my tableview to detail view does not display when i switch views. Labels and everything else seems to work great. I used to get

> 2013-08-30 19:53:46.060 iOS[2849:60b] -[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155d7a00
>
> 2013-08-30 19:53:46.064 iOS[2849:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155d7a00'

but now it shows no errors but image isn't there.

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            PFObject *imageObject = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            PFFile *imagefile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"ImageFiles"];

            [imagefile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                 tempimage= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                }
            }];

            BookDetailViewController *detailVC = (BookDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            NSLog(@"Bookarray=%@", Booksarray);
            NSLog(@"BookIndex=%@", [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            detailVC.Bookname=[[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Books"];
            detailVC.BookDescription= [[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"BookDetails"];
            detailVC.picture=tempimage;
        }
    }


this is what my detail view looks like 


detailview .m

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {


            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        bookTitle.text=_Bookname;
        bookDesc.text=_BookDescription;
        BookImage.image=_picture;
        [UIImageView load];

    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


    }


and detailview h.


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>
    @interface BookDetailViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>  {
        NSArray * images;
    }
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *BookImage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookTitle;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookDesc;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Bookname;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* BookDescription;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage * picture;
    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
[imagefile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         tempimage= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
     }
}];
```

Is an asynchronous download. So, it completes and sets the image into `tempimage` after you have used the (empty) variable and the segue has completed.

You should use a `PFImageView` and pass it the file and allow it to manage downloading and showing the image for you.

Comment: Yeah i read on that only reason i tried this way is because Im not familiar with the PFImageview. I have no idea how to set it up

Comment: Replace your image view with an `PFImageView`, instead of setting its `image` set its `file` And call `loadInBackground`.

Comment: so i did all that and it crashes the app with this error: 2014-03-21 19:22:26.446 BookStore[28222:90b] -[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9acf140
2014-03-21 19:22:26.450 BookStore[28222:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Why does it say in Error UIImageView I changed the property to PFImageView?

Comment: Changing the property doesn't change the class type you create. Change the class when you create the instance in code or the storyboard.

Comment: Yeah I set the class to PFImageView but it crashes the app says unrecognised selector.

Comment: I have an "Imageview" on my detail view controller. So when i click the image view i set the class in inspector to PFImageview and connect it as Iboutlet in my code.

Comment: this is the error i get:    -[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a88800'

Comment: Well, that isn't working as you still have an `UIImageView` instance. Do you have other code that uses that outlet? You can create the `PFImageView` instance in code, but it should work from the storyboard / XIB